# Force console output in ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Is there a way to force the ISE to output to the console, rather than use the Windows forms?

For example with:

```
$host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
```

When run in the ISE you get the nice form version. What if I want to just display it in the console, the way it will be running when I save it and 'Run with Powershell'?

Just want to be able to test how things look without having to leave the ISE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[console]::writeline("testing")` to output text to the ISE console tool window.  But the `[console]::read*` methods don't really work.  Other than that, you are at the mercy of how the host implements the `PSHostUserInterface` interface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface_members(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Helpful but not really what I'm after. I don't think it is possible .

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is possible "out-of-the-box".